# Parse callback is not defined Scrapy python

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to run a scrapy code that scrapes endless scoll as an example (need to learn this technique)
Here's the code

```
import json
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class QuotesScrollSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes-scroll"
    api_url = 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/api/quotes?page={}'
    start_urls = [api_url.format(1)]

def parse(self, response):
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    for quote in data['quotes']:
        yield {'author.name': quote['author']['name'], 'text': quote['text'], 'tags': quote['tags']}

    if data['has_next']:
        next_page = data['page'] + 1
        yield scrapy.Request(url=self.api_url.format(next_page), callback=self.parse)

process = CrawlerProcess({
    'FEEDS': {
        'output.csv': {
            'format': 'csv',
            'encoding': 'utf-8-sig',
        }
    }
})
process.crawl(QuotesScrollSpider)
process.start()
```

When running the code, I got such an error

```
 (referer: None)
2021-01-16 08:52:54 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/api/quotes?page=1> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 90, in _parse
    return self.parse(response, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 93, in parse
    raise NotImplementedError(f'{self.__class__.__name__}.parse callback is not defined')
NotImplementedError: QuotesScrollSpider.parse callback is not defined
2021-01-16 08:52:54 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2021-01-16 08:52:54 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
```

Comment: Are you sure the `def parse(self, response):` is properly indented under the `QuotesScrollSpider` class in your actual code?

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great support. Yes, you are right. I have fixed it.